# No Sound Problem Huawei Matebook D14 I5 Kubuntu 22; Problem I am only getting "Dummy Sound" output, hardware CMOS works OK MS NT10

Tags: sound

Have been using Kubuntu 16, 18, 20 on an I5 Lenovo for years, upgraded to 22.04 and the hardware let go on me half way thru, had to do a fresh install, which works perfectly, am using it now, however I am getting CMOS warnings when I boot, the touch pad is 50% gone, USB system flaky so I thought to buy a new machine.
Bought a Huwaei I5 Matebook D14, slim elegant, nice metallic feel. Everything functions under windows. Did a live "test" install of Kubuntu 22 Jammy, beautiful screen, blindingly quick BUT I have no sound, only "dummy sound" output. Obviously same with Focal Fossa. Is this fixable, maybe due to it being a live test not full install. Anyone know the cure?

Comment: Ubuntu products using the *year* products are different to the far more popular/common ones using the *year.month* format. Kubuntu is also a desktop release that doesn't offer support for the *year* products; so do you mean the *year.month* products?  ie. 20.04 & not 20??  Please be clear with details.

Comment: sorry, in my haste I missed the month,  meant 22.04LTS and 20.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

If pulseaudio recognizes no soundcard (dummy sound indicates that) it is usually missing the driver.

Could be that Huawei used unsupported hardware (by linux).  Either you have to wait until kernel driver for your hardware are available or you have to check if someone has already written a driver for linux.

Checking the threads a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/sgdd6l/no_sound_on_linux_with_matebook_d14_intel/) and [linux mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2079425) are not encouraging. It seems that your hardware is not very well supported by Linux.

Ubuntu offers a list of [certified laptops](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops) which are supported by linux (and Ubuntu).

The best results I had was to buy used Thinkpads (usually T-Series): They last long, are not expensive (as used devices) and work with linux...

Answer (score 0):

Open the text editor with the command:

> nano /etc/modprobe.d/intelDSP.conf

Inside the file, add the following configuration line:

> options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1

Save the changes and reboot your system. Hopefully, this configuration will resolve the issue. It's currently working on my Matebook d14 with Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 6.2.0.

However, if this doesn't fix the problem, for some reason, I found that version 5.15 of the kernel works just fine.
[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=290124)